# Where did the new bounty come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, riddick

In the 2nd movie of The Riddick (*Chronicles of the Riddick*) he goes on a hunt to get the bounty off his head. All the people of the Crematorium die and he becomes leader of the necromongers.
In the 3rd movie of *The Riddick*, he gets killed for his rank and left for dead on a planet but he survives of course.
After identifying himself in the house on the camera-thing. Bounty Hunters show up and want to claim Riddick's head in the box for a bounty. 
I thought Riddick became leader and removed all bounties on his head?

Where did this bounty come from and who made this bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Wiki for Riddick](http://riddick.wikia.com/wiki/Richard_B._Riddick):

> For 5 years Riddick has been neglecting the Necromongers as Lord
>   Marshal and has yet to take the sacred oath or lead them to the
>   Underverse. Several assassins try to take him out by orders of
>   Necromongers commanders, but all of them fail. Seeing that he has let
>   his animal side slip past, he orders Commander Vaako to take him to
>   his home planet. When Riddick arrives on a planet he finds out it is
>   Not-Furya, and the Necromongers betray him trying to kill him...

So it seems that despite being leader of the necromongers, he was too inactive in the role and they tired of him.

This is what the director, David Twohy, was aiming for as stated in [this interview](http://io9.com/riddick-director-explains-how-the-necromonger-king-gets-1057112239):

> The first sequence is about 10 to 15 minutes of him alone on this
>   planet, with no dialogue and just minimal voiceover. And then he goes
>   into a... hibernation. Everything on this planet has tooth and claw.
>   Everything is trying to kill him. So he basically entombs himself, to
>   keep the predators away from him.
>
> And as he falls asleep in his tomb, we flash back to the Necromonger
>   world. We get the sense that while it's great to be King, you have to
>   deal with the assassins outside your room. Sometimes the assassins in
>   your bed, and all the betrayals that take place there. With our
>   limited resources, I was able to do I think a pretty good [job] of
>   that in the movie.

Comment: So the bounty comes from one of the Necro commanders. Does make sense yea, that they found out that he isn't dead.